# Add link to "You must be logged in to checkout" message in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

In the WooCommerce setting page I set the customers to **NOT** be allow to place an order without an account. Then the customer must be logged to do the checkout. I have no problem with this setting. It works fine.

Now if the customer is not logged this message is shown "You must be logged in to checkout." I just need to add a link at the end of this message.

I use this code which allows to change the text and **add a link**

```php
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message( $message ) {
    $message = 'You must be logged in to checkout. <a href="#" id="login-register">login / Register</a>';
    return $message; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', 10, 1 );
```

But the problem is that the html (the link) is printed as it (not rendered as a link).

Take a look at my capture to see what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the filter is passed on to [esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/)

This line is copied from [/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php) line 26 @version 3.5.0

```php
echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
```

---

So if you really want to add HTML you will have to overwrite the template file. The
template file can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`.

Replace

```php
echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
```

With

```php
echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) ) . '&nbsp;<a href="#" id="login-register">login / Register</a>';
```