How to edit WooCommerce Checkout notice "You must be logged in to checkout..."?
I have activated the option on WooCommerce that you must be logged in in order to buy something. When I try to buy something without an account, the notice "You must be logged into checkout. Click here to log in" is displayed. I want to edit the text and add another link that redirect the user to the register page. Where can I find this code in the file manager in order to edit it?
I tried to find it, but I don't know where to look for it.

Doesn't the login page also have a Create Account link of something similiar

If you cannot find the file I would suggest if you do you will not know enough to make the changes. Woocommerce/wordpress is not a good playground for the beginner. So be careful what you do

You are using blocks so there is no hook to use. In case you go back to checkout shortcode - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687964/add-link-to-you-must-be-logged-in-to-checkout-message-in-woocommerce
